# Problem installing Rails_Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, admin

I initially added `gem 'rails_admin', :git => 'git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git'` to my gemfile but I got this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    rails (3.0.4)

  In Gemfile:
    rails_admin depends on
      rails (~> 3.0.7)
```

so I updated to rails 3.0.7 and installed `rails_admin (0.0.1) from git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git (at master)`

I run `rake rails_admin:install` in the console and I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `task'
```

Here is the full trace:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize_tasks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:139:in `load_tasks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/rubyprograms/dreamstill/Rakefile:7
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in  `raw_load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

What's going on and how do I get rails_admin installed?

Comment: Just googling "undefined method task" links you straight to a Stack Overflow question as the first result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known problem with rake 0.9.  To fix it, just do the following:

- Uninstall rake 0.9: `gem uninstall rake -v 0.9`
- Add this to your gemfile: `gem 'rake', '~> 0.8.7`
- Update the bundle: `bundle update`

And you should be good to go.

Comment: When the world switches to Rake 0.9.x (Whenever it's fixed), just change your gemfile to not include the requirement for `0.8.7`, and `bundle update`.